# Рандом с вероятностью появления

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Есть `random(1,3);`, а также есть некая переменная, допустим `x` со значением от 50 и до 700. 
Можно ли реализовать зависимость рандома от значения `x`?

Т.е. Что бы была зависимость от переменной, в том, какое число генерируется. Например при `x = 50` шанс выпадения 3ки минимален (но не исключен), а 1ы максимален (но не исключен).

Comment: а если `x = 350`, что должно быть?

Comment: не опирайся на 700..)) это у меня введено. По хорошему там число N.
Вообще если x=350, то вероятность того что выпадет 1 большая, 2 еще меньше, 3 еще меньше..

Comment: Я совсем не пойму логики, если честно. Но Вам нужно копать в сторону вероятностного распределения (например распределение Гаусса (я пробовал https://github.com/A1essandro/gaussian-distribution), или какое-нибудь линейное распределение)

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать так: есть некое множество натуральных числе А, ему принадлежит промежуток [N,M]. Из множеcтва А берем случайное значение Х и проверяем на принадлежность промежутку [N,M]. Чем больше промежуток [N,M] тем больше вероятность того, что Х ему принадлежит